# In maven multimodule project is it recommended to use package or install

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven multimodule project

```
<modules>
 <module>A</module>
 <module>B</module>
 <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

Module C depends on Module A. In this project structure can you let me know it is recommended to use package or install. I do not have any other requirement to share this project with other projects.

Comment: Using package is enough when all modules are built together, as Maven will link the projects if they are built inside the same reactor. But I would always recommend to use `install`, so that when you build only a sub-module, its dependency will be up to date.

Comment: We do not build sub-module separately.How is this behavior in case of parallel builds?

Comment: If by parallel you mean multi-thread (`-T` option), Maven will only parallelize what can be. For instance, if module C depends on B and B depends on A, there will be nothing parallelized, A will be built, then B then C. There should be no deifference for the reactor part, projects will use reactor output instead of local repo JAR if it detects that the dependency is also built in the same process.

Comment: Can you post the comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When launching a Maven command on multiple modules, if a dependency specified in one module is available as a project being built in the same command, Maven will use the output of the current build as dependency, instead of the JAR present in the local repository.

So it is not *necessary* to use `install` to make the changes of a module available to modules depending on it, as long as these modules are always built together.

Comment: I would conclude the usage to. Never use a `mvn install` only use `mvn package`.